# How do I know if a LastPass One Time Password (OTP) has been used?

Tags: security, lastpass

I intend to give some LastPass one time passwords to close family. Is there a way to know if a one time password has been used? Is it possible to get an email notification that it was used?

Comment: I also would like to know this but can't find if it's possible https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/use-temporary-one-time-passwords-lp030002